# custom iterator "end" dereferenced when passed in to std::vector::assign

Tags: c++, iterator

I am writing a custom iterator and would like to be able to use this to initialize other std containers e.g. `std::vector`. However when I pass my custom iterator into e.g. `std::vector::assign` both the first and last iterators get dereferenced, which triggers an exception due to dereferencing an iterator past the end of its container.

I have followed the code through and this comes from converting the iterator to a raw pointer. The code in question is

```
template <class _Ty>
_NODISCARD constexpr _Ty* to_address(_Ty* const _Val) noexcept {
    static_assert(!is_function_v<_Ty>,
        "N4810 20.10.4 [pointer.conversion]/2: The program is ill-formed if T is a function type.");
    return _Val;
}

template <class _Ptr>
_NODISCARD constexpr auto to_address(const _Ptr& _Val) noexcept {
    if constexpr (_Has_to_address_v<_Ptr>) {
        return pointer_traits<_Ptr>::to_address(_Val);
    } else {
        return _STD to_address(_Val.operator->()); // plain pointer overload must come first
    }
}
```

My custom pointer ends up in the second version of `to_address` whereas `std` type `iterators` end up in the first one because they get converted to raw pointers earlier in the process by an undocumented function `_Get_unwrapped`

I tried overriding `std::to_address` but my version didn't get called and I'm not sure if this is allowed anyway. Also it probably doesn't help as the code snippet above derefernces the iterator before calling `std::to_address`.

So what is the best way to deal with this scenario?

I am using Visual Studio 2019 by the way.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - something is definitely wrong, the end iterator should not be dereferenced when calling `assign`, hinting at a possible bug elsewhere in your code

Comment: The best way to deal with most programming problems is to assume that you caused them yourself. Post your code.

Comment: My guess would be your equality comparator isn't returning true so `assign` keeps de-referencing and iterating past `end`

Comment: @unholysheep  I am assuming I'm doing something wrong. I was hoping someone would say I'm doing something obviously wrong. But if you follow the logic through the assign method in Microsoft's STL, then it seems that it's fallback position to convert an unknown iterator to a raw pointer is to dereference it, then get its address. I hope you can appreciate that a full container and iterator are not easy to break down into a minimal reproducible example, but I'll do my best and post when I have.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but proper way to deal with this is to define a `std::pointer_traits` specialization for your custom pointer, which includes a `to_address` member.